# cannot define variable in function - Go

Tags: go

I am having a little trouble with what I though was a simple task.

I have a function that formats a struct that holds an hour and a minute value and formats it into a string.

```
type Clock struct {
    h int
    m int
}

func (c *Clock) String() string {
    h string
    m string
    if c.m < 10 {
        m := fmt.Sprintf("0%d", c.m)
    } else {
        m := fmt.Sprintf("%d", c.m)
    }
    if c.h < 10 {
        h := fmt.Sprintf("0%d", c.h)
    } else {
        h := fmt.Sprintf("%d", c.h)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", h, m)
}
```

The error I am getting is:

`syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }` for the line `h string` above.

Any idea what is going on here? I figured I would simple use a temporary variable to format  the int values

Comment: And of course outside of learning a little, you should be using the [time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) package for this.

Comment: Yes. I had someone show me how to simplify it to just fmt.Sprintf("%02d:%02d,c.m/60,c.m%60) and I just hold everything in minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare:

```
var h string
var m string
```

And do not use `:=` but `=` when affecting values to `h` and `m` (or you would define those only in their inner scope, instead of reusing the variables defined before)

```
if c.m < 10 {
    m = fmt.Sprintf("0%d", c.m)
} else {
    m = fmt.Sprintf("%d", c.m)
}
if c.h < 10 {
    h = fmt.Sprintf("0%d", c.h)
} else {
    h = fmt.Sprintf("%d", c.h)
}
```

Full example: [play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/_5AzbbxBsd)

Output: `Hello, playground 02:08`

Comment: Awesome. This worked thank you! I will mark this correct when it allows me to.